# Close a popout window and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, php

I made a login logout form and i have the posibility if i want to delete my account . If i press the button `Sterge cont` a popout window wil apear and ask me if i really want to delete this account. If i hit `NU` the account will not be deleted and the window will close but if i hit `DA` the account will be deleted.

The problem which i want to resolve is that if i hit `DA` the window will do the php delete account part and after that will close and redirect my page `profil.php` to `index.php?accountdeleted`

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce5EM.png) is how it looks the user profile.
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGnPO.png) is how it looks the pop up window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just bind the closing of popup event. You can do something like this:

`profil.php`

```
<button type="button" id="delete" onclick="window.open('your_popup.php', 'popup', 'height=400, width=400, top=0, left=0,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no')">Delete</button>
```

Then on the `your_popup.php`:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['confirm_delete'])) {
   // do you query or database delete, etc.


   // at the end
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">self.close(); opener.location.href = "http://localhost/citate_celebre/profil.php";</script>';
}

?>

<form method="POST" action="popup.php">
    <button type="button" id="cancel_delete">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" name="confirm_delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you had the window instance of popup.

```
 var popupWindow = window.open(...) //Open the popup
    popupWindow.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    window.location.href = 'index.php?accountdeleted'; //redirect to new page
};
```